# Cloning multiple layers within group using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have a problem cloning more than one layer within a group. I am not proficient in PyQGIS by any stretch of the imagination. My task is to effectively duplicate all raster layers which names end with `"_DEM"`, and append `" copy"` to the newly formed duplicates or clones. My code snippet for doing only one cloning is as follows:

```
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
substring = "_DEM"
strings_with_substring = [name for name in names if substring in name]
print(strings_with_substring)

DEM = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(strings_with_substring[0])[0]
duplicated = DEM.clone()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(duplicated, False)
group.insertChildNode(3, QgsLayerTreeLayer(duplicated))

dname = duplicated.name()
duplicated.setName(dname + " copy")
```

Is there a way to construct a function or a loop to iterate this piece of code through every instance of the layer list i.e. `strings_with_substring`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
substring = "_DEM"
strings_with_substring = [name for name in names if substring in name]
print(strings_with_substring)

for i in strings_with_substring :
    DEM = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(i)[0]
    duplicated = DEM.clone()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(duplicated, False)
    group.insertChildNode(3, QgsLayerTreeLayer(duplicated))

    dname = duplicated.name()
    duplicated.setName(dname + " copy")
```